# callbacks are not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a critical problem that is my jquery plugins have call backs when I clicked on the elements the callbacks should be called.

I was observed that click event triggering more than one time for that I put unbind working some items well, but some items are not triggering callbacks.

```
$(this).children('li').unbind('click').click(function(){
switch(this.id){
    case 'foo' : options.foocallback();
      break;
    case 'bla' : options.blacallback();
      break;
    .....
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li id="foo">...</li>
<li id="bla">...</li>
...
</ul>
```

now when I click on list items some working fine and calling callbacks

** But some items are not calling the callbacks**

Comment: For list items, shouldn't you want to bind to the `change` event?

Comment: @SpaceBison When would a `<li>` trigger a `change` event?

Comment: Post your related `HTML` code and more jQuery code

Comment: @rajuk the list would trigger the `change` event at any time you select a different option from the one it was selected before

Comment: look at the question now

Comment: @rajuk does your `li` element created dynamically?

Comment: When did you run this code, at pageload? Then, were there any list-items generated dynamically after page-load?

Comment: no dynamic content in the code

Comment: @rajuk does this event binding depending upon some condition? or it is must

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The HTML was posted after I made the comment but I'd assumed select lists and not HTML list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this *(if your event binding don't depend on some conditions)*

***HTML***

```
<ul id="listholder">
  <li id="foo">...</li>
  <li id="bla">...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('#listholder li').on('click', function() {
 switch(this.id){
    case 'foo' : options.foocallback();
      break;
    case 'bla' : options.blacallback();
      break;
    .....
  }
});
```